# Monomials of linearly independent polynomials remains independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I met with a very elementary question on linear algebra which turns out to be quite resistant when I work on it. Any comments or references on either solutions or the possible value of the question will be greatly appreciated.

**Initial problem**: Given $n$ homogeneous polynomials $ F_1,\dots, F_n $ in $R[x_1,\dots, x_m]$ such that $\deg(F_1)= \dots= \deg(F_n)=d$. For a fixed positive integer $k < n$, set $$P_k=\{F_{i_1}F_{i_2} \cdots F_{i_k} \,\vert\, 1\leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k \leq n \}$$
If $ F_1,\dots, F_n $ are linearly independent, that is, $P_1$ is a linearly independent set, then is $P_k$ a linearly independent set for $k > 1$?

The question is trivial for $d=1$. In this case monomials in $F_1,\dots,F_n$ are always linearly independent as we can assume $n \le m$ and $F_i = x_i$ up to a coordinate change.
On the other hand, the question has a negative answer when $d > 1$ if we do not impose any additional conditions. For instance, set $$F_1=x_1^2, F_2=x_1x_2,F_3=x_1x_3,F_4=x_2x_3,$$
then $F_1,F_2,F_3,F_4$ are independent. However, $P_2$ is dependent since $F_1F_4=F_2F_3$.

Now the question becomes:

**Question 1.** Assume $d > 1$. Under what condition will $P_k$ be linearly independent?

A first thought is that we restrict to homogeneous polynomials that are powers of linear polynomials. But this seems to be complicated as well.  For instance, the question for $P_2$ and $d = 2$ goes as follows:

**Question 2.** Let $F_1,\dots, F_n \in R[x_1,\dots, x_m]$ be homogeneous polynomials of degree one such that $F_1^2, F_2^2,\dots, F_n^2$ are linearly independent ($F_1,\dots, F_n$ might be linearly dependent in this case). Under what condition will $F_1^2F_2^2, F_1^2F_3^2,\cdots, F_{n -1}^2F_n^2$ be linearly independent?

Comment: There is a sufficient condition for $P_{n - 1}$ to be a linearly independent set over $R$, assuming $R$ is a field. Let $A$ be an $R$-algebra which is also a unique factorisation domain. For $a \in A$, denote by $\pi(a)$ the set of prime elements of $A$ dividing $a$. Let $E = \{a_1, \dots, a_n\}$ be a subset of $A$ such that $\pi(a_i)$ is not contained in $\bigcup_{j \neq i} \pi(a_j)$ for every $i$ (e.g., the sets $\pi(a_i)$ are pairwise disjoint). Then the set $P_{n - 1}$ consisting of the products of $n - 1$ distinct elements of $E$ is linearly independent over $R$.

Comment: Could you please clarify what $R$ is? It seems likely that your ring of coefficients is the field of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, but I cannot exclude that you meant something different.

Comment: @luc guyot: Just let R
 be either real or complex numbers, and thanks for the editing and comments. The sufficient condition looks nice to work on the context of Question 2 where prime factors are just linear polynomials. Are there any references on  why $P_{n-1}$ is special?

Comment: The case $P_{n - 1}$ is special in the sense that it relates linear dependence over $K$ to divisibility in the ring of polynomials in an obvious way. Similar criteria can be established for $P_k$ with $k < n - 1$, see my answer below, which is a more general version of my comment. However, this is only a remark with limited bearing and it doesn't refer to homogeneous polynomials specifically.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a **long comment** with limited bearing. It consists of two ideas of a similar flavour. Each can be used to address specific instances of the problem.

> **Claim 1.** Let $K$ be a field and let $A$ be $K$-algebra with no zero divisors. Let $E$ be subset of $A$ with $n > 1$ elements and let $k < n$ be such that for every subset $S \subset E$ with $n - k$ elements, there is a valuation $\nu = \nu_S$ defined on the field of fractions of $A$, and non-negative on $A$, such that $$\min_{a \in S} \nu(a) > \sum_{a \in E \setminus S} \nu(a).$$ Then the products of $k$ distinct elements of $E$ are linearly independent over $K$.

**Example 1.** Let $p$ be a prime element of an integral domain $A$ which satisfies the [ascending chain conditions on principal ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascending_chain_condition_on_principal_ideals). The largest power $\nu_p(a)$ of $p$ which divides $a \in A$ defines a non-negative valuation on $A$ which extends to a discrete valuation on the field of fractions of $A$.

**Example 2.** Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field and let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal of $A = K[x_1, \dots, x_m]$. Then $\nu_{\mathfrak{m}}(a) := \sup \{n \ge 0 \, \vert \, a \in \mathfrak{m}^n \}$ defines a non-negative valuation of $A$ which extends to a discrete valuation of $K(x_1, \dots, x_m)$.

> *Proof of Claim 1.* A non-trivial $K$-linear dependence relation between $k$-fold products yields a relation of the form $$a_1 \cdots a_k \in Aa_{k + 1} + \cdots + A a_n$$ for some suitable labelling $E = \{a_1, \dots, a_n\}$.
> Let $S = \{a_{k + 1}, \dots, a_n\}$ and let $\nu = \nu_S$ be the valuation afforded by hypothesis. As $\nu(\sum_{a \in S}Aa) \ge \min_{a \in S} \nu(a)$, we obtain a contradiction.

> **Claim 2.** Let $K$ be field, $A = K[x_1, \dots, x_m]$ and let $\prec$ be a [monomial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order) on $A$. For a polynomial $a \in A$, denote by $\operatorname{LT}(a)$ the leading term with respect to $\prec$ and by $\deg(M) \in \mathbb{N}^m$ the multi-degree of a monomial $M$ of $A$.
> Let $a_1, \dots, a_n$ be elements of $A$ such that the sums $\deg(\operatorname{LT}(a_i)) + \deg(\operatorname{LT}(a_j))$, with $i < j$, are distinct.
> Then the products $a_i a_j$, with $i < j$,
> are linearly independent over $K$.

> *Proof of Claim 2.* By hypothesis, the leading terms $\operatorname{LT}(a_i a_i)$, with $i < j$, are linearly independent over $K$. This ensures that the products $a_i a_j$, with $i < j$, are linearly independent over $K$.